# Unable to translate tooltip text during revision redaction

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, revision-redaction

There's [no text to translate](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Please%20fill%20out) "Please fill out this field." that appears as a tooltip during revision redaction:

> [image]